# Listagem de Elenco: Todos ou apenas aqueles que realmente aparecem "em pessoa"?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, definição

Exatamente como perguntado no próprio título: quando fazendo a listagem de um elenco (ex: *cast* do IMDB) qual a definição correta? Seriam todos aqueles que apareceram "em pessoa" (afinal podem ser pessoas, monstros, personagens de animação...) ou **realmente** todos, mesmo que sejam apenas vistos numa foto -E- mencionados verbalmente por outro dos personagens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só quem aparece em pessoa. Alguém que é apenas mencionado ou mesmo aparece numa foto não faz parte do elenco.

A definição nos dicionários (e.g., o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/elenco)) é clara:

> **Elenco**: Conjunto de atores, cantores, músicos etc. [*i.e., artistas*] ligados a um espetáculo ou empresa

em que geralmente [se entende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_crew) que os artistas que contam são aqueles que

> aparecem em frente da câmera ou dão vozes a personagens.

Qualquer indivíduo que aparece dessa forma no filme (incluindo narradores, atletas, etc.) pode ser considerada um ator, como o próprio IMDb [explicita](https://help.imdb.com/article/contribution/filmography-credits/cast-acting-credits-guidelines/GH3JZC74FVYKKFMD?ref_=helpsrall#general):

> The term "actor" covers everyone whose image or voice appears in a recognised title. This would include documentary subjects, hosts, narrators, athletes, or other people not "acting" in the traditional sense.

Inclusive animais e até mesmo objetos (como a [bola de vôlei](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1012434/) Wilson, de *Cast Away* / Náufrago) podem ser listados no elenco, mas aparições em [pinturas e fotos ficam excluídas](https://help.imdb.com/article/contribution/filmography-credits/cast-acting-credits-guidelines/GH3JZC74FVYKKFMD).

Comment: Beleza, então :)

Comment: Acho que a pregunta não é uma sobra a língua.....

Comment: @Lambie Entendi que a pergunta é sobre o significado exato da palavra, quão abrangente o termo é. Me parece on-topic. Ou entendi errado teu comentário?

Comment: @stafusa O que se encontra o não num elenco na base de dados IMDB não é uma pergunta sobre a língua portuguesa. É uma pergunta sobre conteúdo,  prácticas, e tradução. Isso é sobre "o português"?? Acho que não. Em todo caso, eis um exemplo em português: http://teledramaturgia.com.br/o-auto-da-compadecida/

Comment: Existe base de dados sobre o cinema brasileiro: https://www.telecineplay.com.br/filmes-nacionais

Comment: @Lambie Essa poderia ser uma pergunta interessante: existem diferenças entre o que se entende por "elenco" em português e inglês? De fato parti do pressuposto, nessa resposta, de que ou não existem ou que a acepção do inglês era aceitável, dado que a própria pergunta original menciona a base IMDb. Se você discorda, sugiro fortemente que elabore uma resposta com base nas fontes que você mencionou.

Comment: @stafusa Fiyo, [:)], a tradução de cast é elenco. O problema não é esse. O problema é que a pergunta tem a ver com o conteúdo, digamos, cultural do conceito, em qualquer língua. Continuo pensando que não se trata de uma pergunta sobre o português senão uma indagação sobre o conhecimento de cinema/teatro. Não há diferenças.

Comment: @Lambie Acho que entendi: você ficaria tentado a votar como off-topic, e cabendo melhor no [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), é isso?

Comment: @stafusa Exatamente. :)